# Using a SQL Function in Entity Framework Select

Tags: .net, entity-framework-4

I am using the Devart EF-4 provider for PostgreSQL.

In one of my db tables, I have a column called the_geom which is a PostGis Geometry type column holding a polygon. Long story short, PostGis uses its own binary format to store geometry values, so for it to be usable in my application i need to convert it to Well-Known-Binary (WKB) which is a standardized binary representation of geometry. This can be achieved quite easy in standard SQL by selecting in with

```
select asbinary(the_geom) from mytable
```

The final question is this:
How do I, in Entity Framework, specify to use the asbinary() function to select the_geom column?

Answer (score 5):

There is a bunch of Sql Server functions that you can use in Linq querys in `SqlFunctions` class in `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient` namespace.

Look for sth like that in your Linq Provider library for Postgre, and if you can't find add a computed column with the value of `asbinary(the_geom)` and map that column in EF.

You may even could write sth like that if you look at the decompiled code,

```
public static class SqlFunctions
{
    // Methods
    [EdmFunction("SqlServer", "STR")]
    public static string StringConvert(double? number)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I couldn't find anything like that. I solved my issue by storing the value both as Well-Known-Text (WKT) and WKB. I then used a trigger to update the WKB column everytime the WKT got updated. It's redundant, but gets the job done.