# ASP.NET MVC Search Page - Integer StartsWith On Linq + EF4

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

So, in my last post I was asking how to build a dynamic search filter using LINQ and EF4 ([See Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440642/search-page-with-mvc-linq-ef)) and finally came up with the solution of building the expression as a string and parse it to an expression using the Dynamic LINQ library.

I that solved the problem. I was able to generate a `Expression<Func<TSource, out bool>>` and pass it to the `Where()` method of the `DbSet`. I am also trying to do this using MySql as a database behind EF4.

The problem came when I tried to apply string operations to integers, like searching a database record which consecutive number starts with 1234.

My initial expression was something like: `record.ConsecutiveNumber.ToString().StartsWith("1234")`. Sadly, as expected, things were not that easy as EF4 fails to query the `DbSet` with exception:

> "LINQ to Entities does not recognize
>   the method 'System.String ToString()'
>   method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression."

After some Google search I found that this is a common problem. But C'MON! Is there a way to perform a search function that can search records with a consecutive number starting by "1234"?

How pros implement search features with EF4? This is with a single property filter. What if I wanna add multiple filters? God, my head hurts... :/

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Thought #1: What about a stored procedure? What about calling a MySql stored procedure from Linq? Am I aiming way too high?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the Dynamic LinQ Library:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

And for your question
[How to use "contains" or "like" in a dynamic linq query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455659/how-to-use-contains-or-like-in-a-dynamic-linq-query)

Previously I have gotten the code for this lib and just taken a look inside, it is pretty easy to follow.

Comment: I've tried that library. In the end it generates a Linq lambda expression, when passed to the where method, the app crashes with an exception stating that ToString is not supported in Linq2Entities. I can make contains or like evaluations on String data but what I want is to evaluate if there are any records whose consecutive number starts with some number. Consecutive number is not a string, is an integer, so my first approach was to convert it to string first and then use contains. But no ToString supported.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [SqlFunctions.StringConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) method.  It requires a `double` (or `decimal`) so you'll have to cast your int `ConsecutiveNumber`.

Replace:

```
record.ConsecutiveNumber.ToString().StartsWith("1234")
```

With:

```
SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)record.ConsecutiveNumber).StartsWith("1234")
```

Comment: Is this compatible with EF4 + MySql setup (Code-First)?

Comment: Good question, I can't test that easily.  But given the following post, I'm thinking it's unlikely. :(   http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?47,396177,396177

Comment: Uhm, too bad. I hope this is possible somehow.. :/

Comment: You should have mentioned MySQL in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my thought process on getting it to work. Hopefully it points you in the right direction.

According to other posts SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)record.ConsecutiveNumber) works for Sql Server.

[Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities/3292773#3292773)

And here is relevant information on linq conversions.

[Linq int to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228318/linq-int-to-string/1228507#1228507)

And here is an answer hinting at writing your own sql function for stringconvert

[Using a SQL Function in Entity Framework Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613111/using-a-sql-function-in-entity-framework-select/4613133#4613133)

If SqlFunctions.StringConvert doesn't work for you I'd suggest looking at figuring out how to do it in Sql and then writing your own [`[EdmFunction()]` attribute based method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456845.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got a clue if this will work over Linq to EF or not but presuming that they mapped the Math operations, this might solve your need:

```
record.ConsecutiveNumber / Math.Pow(10, Math.Truncate(Math.Log10(record.ConsecutiveNumber) - 3)) == 1234
```

This is basically dividing the number by a power of 10 just big enough to leave the first 4 digits.

I know this is very hacky and inefficient even if it works, but there you go. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Any method calls in a LINQ to Entities query that are not explicitly mapped to a canonical function will result in a runtime NotSupportedException exception being thrown.
```

Check mapping canonical function here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738681.aspx

In this case, you can use Math function. (I don't think code first can use in product project at that time)